# Как установить KDE Plasma 5 в Centos 7?

Tags: centos7, kde

У кого есть пошаговая инструкция с командами, для установки plasma 5 в Centos 7?

У нас в организации идёт переход на отечественное ПО, и там система на основе Centos 7 построена, смотриться не очень. хотелось бы хоть поставить плазму, но оказалось, что её компилить нужно из исходников, сам даже не знаю с чего начать...

Может достаточно какой-то репозиторий подключить и выполнить пару команд в консоли

Answer (score 0):

Первая же ссылка в гугле - https://linuxconfig.org/installation-of-kde-desktop-environment-on-centos-7

1. `sudo yum groupinstall 'KDE' 'X Window System'`
2. `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`
3. `reboot`

Comment: Зачем вы мне тут KDE 4 подсовывает?  Вы хоть пробовали установить KDE Plasma 5 на centos 7 прежде чем на первую попавшуюся ссылку меня отправлять?

Comment: Подсуну ка я вам еще один вариант, на centOS 8 работает, в вашем случае не могу знать - `yum groupinstall "KDE Plasma Workspace"`

Comment: На 8 то работать будет а на 7 нет.